# Flash SharedObject Reader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

Can anybody recommend a good Flash SharedObject reader? There is one included in FlashDevelop, but it usually returns errors like `"Invalid FileSize signature. Received X expecting Y"`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice I've ever had debugging Flash applications is Flash Firebug. Pro costs 10$ a year, but it totally worths it. It has everything to help you debug you Flash applicaitons, including a SharedObject reader you're looking for.

P.S. You'll have to install [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/products/download.html?product=firefox-15.0.1) and Firebug (also an addon) for this addon.
Both of these can be aquired by searching Firefox's built-in add-ons.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a very useful tool, however I'm not sure if it will work for me. Sorry, I neglected to mention that I'm doing mobile (iOS and Android) development using Flash and Adobe Air. So, the .swf file never gets inside a web browser. Do yo think I can still use Flash Firebug for my purposes?

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that.. I don't think so, you can only debug SWF-s inside Firefox. Sorry.

Comment: That's my fault, should have mentioned that in the question :)